# V Fork happened yet?

Tags: monero-forks

I purchased 1 monero coin several months ago and is being held in a Freewallet. Has the Fork happened yet? Do I have 10 coins now or just 1?

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for MoneroV in Freewallet. Unless they support the fork, you will not be able to claim MoneroV.

As a reminder, Freewallet controls your private keys. If you used a different application such as Monerujo, Cake Wallet, or X Wallet, you could restore your Monero (including possibly claiming coins) on another device.

Answer (score 1):

You may have 1 XMR and 10 XMV but freewallet is a scam, you may just have nothing.
Also to claim your 10 XMV airdrop, you must enter your private keys in XMV wallet, which could be a scam to get your XMR as the wallet code has not been disclosed, and you may also be part of a global privacy attack against monero.
Luckily for all of us (and that's the reason it is a scam) freewallet own the private keys (and therefore own your coins) and you would not be able to claim the airdrop shitcoin, neither you're even sure you could withdraw your XMR on a real, safe, wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If we decide to support XMV, our users will be credited with XMV coins accordingly. No private keys will be required for that.
As it was mentioned here, the fact that some platform does not support XMV shall not mean a wallet provider is a scam. We still consider the possibility to support this fork and will notify our users by email, on Facebook, and on Twitter if we start supporting these coins.

Comment: "No private keys will be required for that" is incorrect.